# ng-click does not work in angular svg on ipad but ng-swipe works

Tags: angularjs, ipad, svg, mobile, angular-ng

I added ng-click and I am using angular-touch in an embedded svg in my Angular app. ng-click works fine on desktop, but it doesn't work on iPad. However, I can swipe left and right to invoke my click handler fine on iPad.

Any ideas?

```
<rect id="path-9" x="0" y="0" width="174" height="30" rx="15" ng-click="showConfirm($event, 4)" ng-swipe-left="showConfirm($event, 4)" ng-swipe-right="showConfirm($event, 4)"></rect>
```